# Когда в начало вписываю тег *doctype*, пропадает одна кнопка из второго меню и стили css для менюшек. Не загораются кнопки

Tags: html, css

Сделал свою первую страничку сайта. Без `<!doctype html>` все работает замечательно - меню работают. Когда в начало вписываю тег *doctype*, пропадает одна кнопка из второго меню и стили css. Вообще такое впечатление, что кроме разметки перестают использоваться другие элементы кода: не загорается ни одна кнопка  в меню

```
 a:hover { 
    background-position: 0 -75.1;
```

и т.п. Как правильно добавить *doctype* или что нужно исправить, для того, чтобы все работало корректно?

Вот начало странички:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ВДК</title>
</head>
```

Так не работает:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ВДК</title>
</head>
```

Если *doctype* убрать, то все работает.

```css
.socialy ul {
    background-position:center;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

.socialy li { 
    float:left; 
}

.socialy a {
    display: block;
    margin-left:15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left:10px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 64px;
    text-indent:-99999px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0px; 

}

.socialy a:hover { 
    background-position: 0 -70; 
}

.socialy a.face { 
    background-image: url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=FB&w=50&h=50&txttrack=0g"); 
}

.socialy a.insta {
    background-image:url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=IG&w=50&h=50&txttrack=0"); 
}

.socialy a.VK {
 background-image:url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=VK&w=50&h=50&txttrack=0"); 
}

.socialy a.yto {
    background-image:url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=YT&w=50&h=50&txttrack=0"); 
}
```

```html
<ul class="socialy">
      <li><a href="https://" class="face">but1</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://" class="insta">but2</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://" class="vk">but3</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://" class="yto">but4</a></li>
</ul>
```

http://www.imageup.ru/img133/2358063/21.jpg Вот так выглядеть должно...
http://www.imageup.ru/img133/2358064/1-1.jpg  вот так выглядит после добавления доктайп при том что курсор мыши наведен на ту же кнопку

Comment: полный код вашего html плиз. Вообще пишется <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: все работает http://jsbin.com/viyicaqolu/edit?html,css,output что не так?

Comment: у меня же не пропала. А почему они должны подсвечиваться?

Comment: Имею в виду картинка пропадает и a.hover получается не работает как подсветка кнопки...

Comment: я вам сказал полный код, вы не хотите помощи, удачи.

Comment: Как же не хочу, еслиб не хотел вопросы бы не спрашивал=) добавил css в вопрос...

Comment: картинок не вижу, но вы кое-где пишите `/img/leftB.png`, а кое-где с двоеточием `../img/leftB.png`. Определитесь где ваши картинки находятся, и писать надо в кавычках `background-image:url("../img/tbar.png");`

Comment: сюда вставьте весь код с картинками http://jsbin.com/?html,css,js,output чтобы их было видно.

Comment: Убрал лишний код из вопроса, оставил только минимальный воспроизводимый пример ошибки.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В [спецификации HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-doctype) есть заметка по этому поводу:

> DOCTYPEs are required for legacy reasons. When omitted, browsers tend to use a different rendering mode that is incompatible with some specifications. Including the DOCTYPE in a document ensures that the browser makes a best-effort attempt at following the relevant specifications.

И собственно, по крайней мере в Google Chrome, если не указывать doctype, то CSS-селекторы становятся регистронезависимыми, вопреки спецификации.

3-я кнопка у вас не отображается именно из-за этого - различается регистр в названии класса внутри документа:

```
<li><a href="http://" class="vk">but3</a></li>
```

и в css:

```
.socialy a.VK {
    background-image:url("/img/vkB.png"); 
}
```

Соответственно при указанном `<!doctype html>`(css-селекторы регистро-зависимы) браузер пытается применить вышеуказанное CSS-правило к элементам `a` c классом `VK`(вместо `vk`), являющихся потомками элементов с классом `.socialy` - однако таких элементов в вашем HTML-документе попросту нет. Правило не применяется - картинка не показывается.

---

А ещё без указанного doctype, Google Chrome считает пиксели единицей измерения по умолчанию, если их не указывать. А с `<!doctype html>` - отсутствие единицы измерения считается ошибкой.

Соответственно вашем правиле:

```
a:hover { 
    background-position: 0 -70; 
}
```

Достаточно было указать единицу измерения - т.к. это правило касается фоновой картинки, то именно пиксели:

```
a:hover { 
    background-position: 0 -70px; 
}
```

Comment: Огромное человеческое Вам спасибо! Кнопка отображается но  a:hover { 
    background-position: 0 -75.1;
Не работает т.е. картинка на фоне не меняется... С этим можно что то накрутить?

Comment: @Саня, с этим ещё проще - вы единицу(px) измерения просто не указали. Правильно - `a:hover { background-position: 0 -70px }` :)

Comment: =) Для первого блина простительно=) Что бы я без Вас делал уже весь мозг поломал! Спасибо еще раз, выручили прям по существу и в точечку!=)